# SQL Server Templates - How Do I Escape The Less Than Character?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, templates, ssms

I like to use SQL Server 2005 templates to run frequently used queries. You can include parameters in your templates using this syntax:

```
<LastName, varchar, 'Bob'>
```

I have a query that needs the less than or equals to operator **<=** but unfortunately the SQL Server 2005 template interprets that as the start of a parameter. I have been unable to find a way to use the **<** (less than character) as a literal.

Comment: can you post the whole query?

Comment: isn't a single quote ' the escape character?

Comment: +1 just for mentioning SSMS query templates. Cool feature, way underrated imho.

Comment: +1, you can put stackoverflow code snips+notes in these to help remember useful things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when I Specify Values for Template Parameters, this runs fine for me:

```
select * from <xyz, varchar,YourTable> WHERE ID<=1000 AND ID>=20000
```

perhaps you do not have every parameter's "<" and ">" paired properly

**EDIT**  I see the problem now:

```
SELECT * FROM <xyz, varchar,YourTable> WHERE ID<=1000 AND ID>=20000 AND <xyz2,varchar,YourColumn> IS NOT NULL
```

results in:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE IDYourColumn IS NOT NULL
```

try making the "<" character into a parameter, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <xyz, varchar,YourTable> WHERE ID<lessthan,char,<>=1000
AND ID>=20000 AND <<xyz2,varchar,YourColumn> IS NOT NULL
```

it results in:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID<=1000
AND ID>=20000 AND YourColumn IS NOT NULL
```

OR split the lines, line breaks seem to make a difference:

```
SELECT * FROM <xyz, varchar,YourTable> WHERE ID<=1000 AND ID>=20000 
AND <xyz2,varchar,YourColumn> IS NOT NULL
```

results in:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID<=1000 AND ID>=20000 
AND YourColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

With template

```
select top 10 * from syscolumns
where <xtype, varchar(128), xtype <= 60>
```

If you select (menu) Query > Specify Values for template parameters, the default value for replacement is "xtype <= 60", which is correct, and upon substitution, the resulting query text is

```
select top 10 * from syscolumns
where xtype <= 60
```

which is exactly what one would expect.  In other words, it does not appear to be the case that the "<" symbol needs to be escaped.  However, ">" is more problematic:

```
select top 10 * from syscolumns
where <xtype, varchar(128), xtype >= 60>
```

This will fail when opening the "specify values" dialog.  However, in this instance, it is fine to specify

```
select top 10 * from syscolumns
where <xtype, varchar(128), value>
```

and enter

```
xtype >= 60
```

in the "value" field for replacement.  This produces

```
select top 10 * from syscolumns
where xtype >= 60
```

which is again as one would expect.  So it would seem that the default value for replacement may not contain a ">".